# I want to know about TransactionSearch API ( which is deprecated ) for 2017 on PayPal

Tags: paypal

I know before 2017, the PayPal provides the Api which I can get all the transaction history via Rest API .
that is TransactionSearch using NVP.
but PayPal says it has been deprecated.
so I want to know ,how can I get transaction history via PayPal API.
Looking forward your help.

Comment: Did you find an alternative to the NVP API that works for searching your transactions?

Answer (score 2):

Although PayPal deprecated the classic API, you can also use all of the classic APIs(containing TransactionSearch API), PayPal just will not renew or develop new feature. But all of current functions can be used.

And if you want to use transaction search function under REST API, please refer following URL.
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/payments/paypal-payments/?mark=list%20payment#search-payment-details

Please refer "List payments with transaction details" section. 
API document: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/#payment_list

Comment: I want to get Transaction history under REST API but getting transaction using this 

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/#payment_list

is only getting transactions which is created by create payment api.I want to get all the transaction history

Comment: The rest payment API seems to search specific types of payments made as OP points out. It does not search transactions, for example, resulting from the agreement API, which are Express Checkout payments (from what PP told me). Basically useless for a lot of people.